# Does Ubuntu need this EFI partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to migrate my system to a SSD, and there's this 512mb EFI partition that's giving me trouble. Is this thing a leftover from Windows 8? Does Ubuntu need it to function properly? I'm not using dual boot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu needs that EFI partition. UEFI is a (relatively) new method of booting for operating systems, and is much more featured than legacy/BIOS boot. Look it up for some more details.

If you don't copy it over, you aren't going to be able to boot, as it stores the bootloader files for OSes that support EFI. There may be Windows stuff left over, but there's also almost definitely GRUB files in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're copying an existing Ubuntu system, yes, then you must also copy the EFI partition.

If you can do a fresh installation, you might also decide to do a legacy install which does not need an EFI partition. There's no way to convert an installed system from UEFI to Legacy or vice versa. At least I don't know any, it's definitely not trivial.

To explain what this EFI partition is about:

It's needed for newer systems that use the (U)EFI technology to boot. This partition is common for all installed operating systems. Every bootloader stores some files there that describe how it wishes to be invoked by the UEFI system.

Comment: Converting from EFI-mode to BIOS-mode booting or vice-versa is possible, and is not all that hard if you know how: You must install an appropriate boot loader for the desired boot mode and reconfigure the firmware to use that boot mode. Details depend on which way you're converting and what boot loader you want to use (GRUB, LILO, ELILO, EFI stub loader, etc.)